# CakeLog doesn't write to debug.log in Shell

Tags: cakephp, logging, cakephp-2.1

I wrote a shell program on CakePHP 2.1, and I wanted to write log. So I wrote like below.

```
CakeLog::write(LOG_DEBUG, $msg);
```

I want to write the $msg to `debug.log`, but it wrote to `error.log`.
Is there someone who solve this problem?
Please tell me how to write to `debug.log`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
CakeLog::write('debug', $msg);
```

Comment: Thanks, arilia.  
  
I tried your code, but it seem to not take effect.  
But I read the source code of CakeLog, and find out that it should be take effect... I don't know why it doesn't work.  
  
But it's my pleasure you answered this !

Answer (score 1):

At first, enable debug in `/app/config/core.php`:

```
Configure::write('debug', 1);
```

At second, write your log into `/app/tmp/logs/debug.log` using the following code:

```
Debugger::log("My Log");
```

Comment: Thanks! Wow, I didn't know "Debugger::log". I'll try it.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to include

```
App::uses('CakeLogInterface', 'Log');
```

at the top of your shell or it won't work

Comment: If that were the problem - it'd be a fatal error. -1.